# Keep position after browser back button when using infinite scrolling

Tags: jquery

Somebody created an infinite scroller for my webshop. This works very good except for one thing. When you're halfway the page and click on a product you go to the product page. When an user hits the browser back button the user goes back to the page with the infinite scroller. Problem is that the script loads all the products again on the position where the user clicked the product the first time. In other words, when you hit the back button all the products are loaded again. 
After searching this site I've read you can do something with window.loacation.hash. Problem is that I'm a beginner in JS and Jquery so I don't have a clue how this would fit into the code below. Any help is more then welcome...

Sorry for any mistakes in the code below but I had to unminify the script....

My code

```
var currentPage = {{ collection.page }};
var collectionPages = {{ collection.pages }};
var category = '{{ collection.internal.url }}';
var appendProduct = function (product) {
    if (currentPage == 1) {
        return false
    }
    $('<div class="product"></div>').html(product).appendTo($(".productsGrid"));
    var i = 1;
    $('.product').each(function () {
        if (i++ % 3 == 0) $(this).addClass('last')
    })
};
var loadProducts = function () {
    var url = "http://www.riemen-tekoop.nl/" + category + "/page" + currentPage + ".ajax" + window.location.search;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data.products, function (index, product) {
            var imageUrl = product.image.replace('50x50x2', '210x175x2');
            var itemHtml = '' + '<a href="' + product.url + '" title="' + product.title + ' ' + product.brand.title + '"><img src="' + imageUrl + '" width="210" height="175" alt="' + product.title + ' ' + product.brand.title + '" title="' + product.title + ' ' + product.brand.title + '"/>';
            if (product.price.price_old) {
                itemHtml = itemHtml + '<div class="perc">' + (((+product.price.price / product.price.price_old) * 100) - 100).toFixed(0) + '%</div>'
            }
            itemHtml = itemHtml + '<div class="caption" style="display:none;"><a href="' + product.url + '" class="opener">Quick view</a></div>' + '</a>' + '<div class="info">' + '<h3>' + '<a href="' + product.url + '" title="' + product.title + ' ' + product.brand.title + '">' + product.title + ' ' + product.brand.title + '</a>' + '</h3>' + '<div class="gridAddToCart">' + '<a class="btnLink" href="' + product.url + '" title="' + product.title + ' ' + product.brand.title + '" rel="nofollow" alt="Bekijk details"><span>{{ '
            Details ' | t }}</span></a>' + '<a class="btnWishlist" href="{{ ' / account / wishlistAdd / ' }}' + product.id + '" title="{{ '
            Add to wishlist ' | t }}" rel="nofollow" alt="Zet op {{ '
            Wishlist ' | t }}"></a>' + '</div>' + '<div class="price"><strong>' + product.price.price_money + '</strong>';
            if (product.price.price_old) {
                itemHtml = itemHtml + ' <span>' + product.price.price_old_money + '</span>'
            }
            itemHtml = itemHtml + '<div class="clear"></div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '<span class="imgshadow"></span>';
            appendProduct(itemHtml)
        });
        $("#overlay").fadeOut();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            update()
        })
    })
};
loadProducts();
var isUpdating = false;
var update = function () {
    if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - 4000) {
        if (currentPage < collectionPages && !isUpdating) {
            isUpdating = true;
            currentPage++;
            $("#overlay").fadeIn();
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            setTimeout(function () {
                loadProducts();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    isUpdating = false
                }, 500)
            }, 500)
        }
    }
};
$(window).scroll(function () {
    update()
});
```